# Vertically Scale an image in multiple background images

Tags: html, css

I'm Making a multiple background image, and I want an image(flower image) to be going vertically if the browser is been resize accordingly.

Below is a screenshot of the background image I want the flower hand to go up anytime I'm resizing the browser.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDFBZ.jpg

Below is my code the second URL is the image I want to go up(vertical) whenever I'm resizing the browser.

```
.desktopbackground {
  background: url("wp-content/uploads/2019/02/mobile-Girl-2.0.png") 50px bottom no-repeat, 
              url("/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Flower-3.0.png") 100% -10% no-repeat,
              url("/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/desktop-Background-1.0.jpg") center no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size:515px,555px,cover;    
}
```

I've tried everything but it keeps going horizontal.

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle/codepen link to understand your problem?

Comment: HI, This is the website link https://tinynature.co.nz/

Comment: I am looking at the website and I see the flower image move horizontally when the browser is resized.  What do you mean "move up".  Do you want it off the screen when the height is shorter?

Comment: I want it when I'm resizing the window the flower image should be going vertically perhaps making it suit different screen sizes better, right now it's going horizontally when you're resizing the window.

Comment: You should use relative units like "40vh" instead of fixed units like "515px" for the background size and it will resize with the window.